# 3-level topology with SaltStack Salt Syndic performs very slowly

Tags: salt-stack

I've designed a 3-level infrastructure with 3 virtual machines (testfer-01, testfer-02 & testfer-03) and for the 3rd one is not possible to reach the 1st one so the 2nd must act as a middleman. To that end I've used the salt-syndic daemon in this second layer. More info: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/topology/syndic.html

To sum up, this is what is running on each VM:

```
testfer-01: salt-master
testfer-02: salt-master, salt-syndic & salt-minion
testfer-03: salt-minion
```

And I've set up the following files (every other option is set by default):

*testfer-01:/etc/salt/master:*

```
order_masters: True
```

*testfer-02:/etc/salt/master:*

```
syndic_master: testfer-01
```

*testfer-02:/etc/salt/minion:*

```
master: testfer-01
```

*testfer-03:/etc/salt/minion:*

```
master: testfer-02
```

Then, once the keys have been accepted I've "successfully" tested the connectivity from the top-layer machine. However, is taking **too much** time:

```
[root@testfer-01 ~]# time salt '*' test.ping
testfer-02.local:
    True
testfer-03.local:
    True

real    0m15.412s
user    0m0.716s
sys     0m0.216s
```

Anyone have any idea why?

EDIT: The command/module output is displayed (those "True" strings in this example) quite fast (no more than 2secs). But then, if I strace the process this one shows a lot of gettimeofday calls for around 10 more seconds...

```
...
poll([{fd=30, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)    = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1421223627, 431608}, NULL) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1421223627, 441964}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=30, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)    = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1421223627, 442102}, NULL) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1421223627, 452523}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=30, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)    = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1421223627, 452720}, NULL) = 0
...
```

Comment: We're having the same problem at work. I think it's a known bug: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/18593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just release version 2016.3 on repo.saltstack.com and this has several very important speed improvements and fixes for the syndic. Can you test against that?

Comment: I have re-tested the same topology configuration this time with mentioned version 2016.3. As @Utah_Dave said, I have observed a 3x performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

With version 2016.3 and no other single modification:

```
[root@testfer-01 ~]# salt-master --version
salt-master 2016.3.1 (Boron)
[root@testfer-01 ~]# time salt '*' test.ping
testfer-02:
    True
testfer-03:
    True

real    0m5.744s
user    0m0.552s
sys     0m0.123s
```